# Generating Bitmap in C# - Deprecated?

Tags: c#, bitmap, png, .net-4.5, bitmapimage

I am trying to declare and initialize a Bitmap in C#, but it does not seem to find the library.  It just tells me to create the Bitmap class.  Even by adding "`using System.Drawing`" manually has no effect.

```
using System.Drawing

...

Bitmap img = new Bitmap(500, 500);
```

Any ideas?  I am using the .NET Framework 4.5, and according to Microsoft:

```
.NET Framework
Supported in: 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
```

If it is deprecated, how can I create a Bitmap in C# using the .Net Framework 4.5?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Just that it is unidentified.  SLaks was right tho, thx.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  May I ask why?

Comment: This did not deserve a downvote... (wasn't me, just advocating)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to add a reference to the assembly it's defined in; namely, `System.Drawing.dll`.